# Programmatically removing a ViewPager, when are (or how can I ensure) contained Fragments are destroyed?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Having searched regarding this issue beforehand, I can find many discussions regarding dynamically adding and removing selected `Fragment`s from a `ViewPager`. What I'm actually concerned about here however is how I can programmatically remove an entire `ViewPager` 'cleanly' from its containing `ViewGroup`, when that `ViewPager` has been used to display `Fragment`s via a `FragmentPagerAdapter`, and ensure that the contained `Fragment`s are destroyed properly.

To expand on the question a bit more, I have a landscape two-pane layout where a selection is made from a list within a `Fragment` on the left-hand-side, and chosen content is then placed on the right within a `FrameLayout`. The key thing is that the content may or may not be paginated. Therefore, the content must either be displayed in a `ViewPager` format, or if it is not paginated then it shall be represented by a single `Fragment` directly.

To show a single `Fragment`, I simply perform a `FragmentTransaction` as you normally would in order to place the `Fragment` into the `FrameLayout` container. If on the other hand it's paginated content to be shown, then instead I create a `ViewPager` and add it as a child of the `FrameLayout`.

When I need to change the content, then if the previous content was a stand-alone `Fragment` then I can simply remove it via `FragmentTransaction` `.remove()`. When I do this, the `Fragment` goes through the `onPause()` ... `onDestroy()` cycle as expected. If the previous content was a `ViewPager` then I remove it from the `FrameLayout` using `.removeAllViews()`. Here I come to the problem: I don't see any of the `onPause()` ... `onDestroy()` methods being called in any of the `Fragment`s that were held within that `ViewPager` via the `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

From a user point of view, the application works fine. After several rounds of `ViewPager` being removed, I can see the GC reclaiming memory. However, I don't like the fact that those `Fragment`s' end of life methods aren't called as I can't do any cleanup within them, and it just doesn't seem 'right'.

Is there a method I can hook into in order to remove the `ViewPager`'s `Fragment`s when the `ViewPager` is detached from its parent, perhaps? In other words, when I know that the `ViewGroup` is no longer in used, I would perform `FragmentTransaction`s somewhere (perhaps in the `FragmentPagerAdapter`) to remove those `Fragment`s.

Alternatively, I realise that I could just keep the `ViewPager` on the right permanently, and dynamically swap the `Fragment`s within it. Of course it simply would not matter that at certain times it would only hold one page. If this would be a better way to go then I shall refactor my code to do this, but I would appreciate opinions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> However, I don't like the fact that those Fragments' end of life methods aren't called as I can't do any cleanup within them, and it just doesn't seem 'right'.

They should get cleaned up when the activity is destroyed, if that is not too late for you (e.g., heap issues).

> In other words, when I know that the ViewGroup is no longer in used, I would perform FragmentTransactions somewhere (perhaps in the FragmentPagerAdapter) to remove those Fragments.

You did not execute the transactions to put the fragments there. Hence, you cannot readily execute the transactions to remove the fragments. If you switch to `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, and call `setAdapter(null)`, it should cause all existing fragments in the pager to be destroyed, by my reading of the source code. `FragmentPagerAdapter` never uses `remove()`, but `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` does, from its `destroyItem()` method, and all extant fragments are destroyed via `destroyItem()` when a new adapter (or `null`) is supplied to `setAdapter()`.

Comment: Thank you. A solution I came to just now is to use `FragmentManager` within `destroyItem` to remove the `Fragment`. I also return `PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE` from `getItemPosition` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. By doing this prior to removing the `ViewPager`, the `Fragment`s' `onDestroy` is called and I'm happy. Do you see any issues with this? The reason for using `FragmentPagerAdapter` is because I want all `Fragment`s (a small number) to stay around, because my UI requires that user data is persisted from all fragments in response to a single accept button action.

Comment: @Trevor: "Do you see any issues with this?" -- that should be OK, though be careful when taking on any updates to the Android Support package. For all we know, they'll change the behavior such that Android also tries destroying the fragments, and you may wind up with errors and have to back out your own destroy logic.

Comment: Thank you again, and understood. Seems what I have now then is best of both worlds: Using `FragmentPagerAdapter` means that paging away from a `Fragment` doesn't destroy it, but by extending `destroyItem` to remove the fragment just like `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` does, I can remove Fragments when I want. (I appreciate requiring all attached fragments to stay around so that I can request them to persist user-input data at once could be frowned upon, but otherwise I would have to refactor so that all Fragments passed this data to the main Activity, which I'd rather avoid.)

Comment: @Trevor can u please provide the code of the solution ? I would be grateful thanks