# What to determine a Fragment restore upon Activity re-create?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, fragmenttransaction

For `View`s having IDs, they will be auto-saved when calling `super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);`.

For `Fragment`s added to an `Activity`, what are the cases that it will be re-created when its `Activity` is re-created (e.g. screen rotation), and what are the cases it will not? What to determine? What is the rule?

*So far, i have tried the following cases. But trial-n-error does not mean any rules or solutions.*

Cases when `Fragment`s are re-stored:

1. Normal case: `FragmentTransaction.add()` to the layout with an ID.
2. Fragment without a UI: `FragmentTransaction.add()` to a tag only

Cases when `Fragment`s are **NOT** re-stored:

1. When `super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);` is skipped.
2. Restored `Fragment`s in a UI without a matching ID.

What is the general rule? Anything i missed in the documentation?

Thanks in advance.

---

## Edit:

To my understanding, and experiments, ALL dynamically (programmatically) added `Fragment`s are saved upon their `Activity` calling `super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)`.

- **ALL dynamically (programmatically) added `Fragment`s** includes,

  - `Fragment`s with only a tag (no UI),
  - `Fragment`s attached to a `View` (with UI),
  - and `Fragment`s with *both* an UI and a tag.
  - *(is there any types else?)*

Regarding restoring a `Fragment` with an UI into a layout that with no matching ID, the `Fragment` is indeed re-created. It just cannot be shown visually in the layout, with the following warning message:

```
04-08 11:41:22.445: W/PhoneWindow(9853): Previously focused view reported id 2131165226 during save, but can't be found during restore.
```

Once we are back into an UI with its matching ID, it will be restored correctly.

---

## i am *still* looking forward to some reliable references and your opinions!

Comment: With the [source codes](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app), all the questions can be solved :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, you can see it here: [After screen rotation, findFragmentById() returns a fragment, even if there's no such ID inside the layout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19534746/816416)

**The Android Developer Documentation at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html quotes this:**

> When a configuration change causes the activity hosting these
>   fragments to restart, its new instance may use a different layout that
>   doesn't include the same fragments as the previous layout. In this
>   case all of the previous fragments will still be instantiated and
>   running in the new instance. However, any that are no longer
>   associated with a  tag in the view hierarchy will not have
>   their content view created and will return false from isInLayout().
>   (The code here also shows how you can determine if a fragment placed
>   in a container is no longer running in a layout with that container
>   and avoid creating its view hierarchy in that case.)

That means, we have to check screen orientation than believing in null pointer checks.