# Do something right before Screen Rotation?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-manifest, screen-orientation, onconfigurationchanged

i want to `do_something()` whenever the device rotates from Portrait to Landscape.

i have added `<activity android:configChanges="orientation" >` in my manifest. So `onConfigurationChanged()` will be called whenever i rotate my device. And it will *not* re-create the Activity.

In my `onConfigurationChanged()` function:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        do_something();
    }
    then_fire_off_the_screen_rotation_as_normal();
    // which means re-start the Activity
    // i expect it will fire off onSaveInstanceState() -> onPause() -> onStop() -> onDestroy() -> onCreate() -> onStart() -> onRestoreInstanceState() -> onResume()
}
```

My problem is, i dont know what can i do in `then_fire_off_the_screen_rotation_as_normal()`.

i have tried using `setRequestedOrientation()` but it seems it is not the function serving this purpose:

When i pass in `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED`, `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR`, or `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER`, the Activity is still *not* re-started. (Just like not calling.)

When i pass in `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR`, the orientation sensor turned off. (As it said.)

When i pass in `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE`, the Activity was **Force Close** with `AndroidRuntime:NullPointerException`.

---

*(Be specific: It is because there are programmatically added Fragments in the Portrait layout, but not in the Landscape layout. In the `do_something()` function, i will remove those Fragments, as they are not needed in Landscape mode.)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, i guess this simple way can serve what i want to:

**Not to** add `<activity android:configChanges="orientation" >`. Means NO NEED OVERRIDE `onConfigurationChanged()`.

In `onSaveInstanceState()`:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        do_something();
    }
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

* Be sure you `do_something()` ***before*** `super.onSaveInstanceState()`.

*(Because in my case, i remove the Fragments from the Layout, and from the Activity. If it is after `super.onSaveInstanceState()`, the Layout will already be saved into the Bundle. Then the Fragments will **also** be re-created after the Activity re-creates. ###)*

### I have proved this phenomenon. But the reason of [***What to determine a Fragment restore upon Activity re-create?***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555964/what-to-determine-a-fragment-restore-upon-activity-re-create) is just by my guess. If you have any ideas about it, please answer [my another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555964/what-to-determine-a-fragment-restore-upon-activity-re-create). Thanks!

---

Well, further improvement on the method above, which fixes the problem raised in the first comment: (still simple)

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    if (isPortrait2Landscape()) {
        do_something();
    }
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

private boolean isPortrait2Landscape() {
    return isDevicePortrait() && (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}
```

and the `isDevicePortrait()` would be like:

```
private boolean isDevicePortrait() {
    return (findViewById(R.id.A_View_Only_In_Portrait) != null);
}
```

* Notice that we ***cannot*** use `getResources().getConfiguration().orientation` to determine if the device is *currently literally* Portrait. It is because the `Resources` object is changed ***RIGHT AFTER*** the screen rotates - ***EVEN BEFORE*** `onSaveInstanceState()` is called!!

If you do not want to use `findViewById()` to test orientation (for any reasons, and it's not so neat afterall), keep a global variable `private int current_orientation;` and initialise it by `current_orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;` in `onCreate()`. This seems neater. But we should be aware ***not to*** change it anywhere during the Activity lifecycle.

Comment: Well, i already think of a determining weakness of this approach. While we are at Landscape mode, then switch apps, or lock screen, which will **also** trigger `do_something()`, which it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

```
 // which means re-start the Activity
 // i expect it will fire off onSaveInstanceState() -> onPause() -> onStop() -> onDestroy() -> onCreate() -> onStart() -> onRestoreInstanceState() -> onResume()
```

This assumption that onPause(), onStop(), etc. will fire is not correct. By using `onConfigurationChanged` you are telling Android to not go through those steps and instead you will handle the saving of information on the layout in temp variables and then recall the `InitializeUI()` and then set the layout back to how you want. I will post an example of something I have that is similar and working for me in one moment.

Edit: Here is the sample

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Log.i("configChange", "configChange");

    String tmp = connect.getText().toString();
    boolean onTmp = on.isEnabled();
    boolean offTmp = off.isEnabled();
    boolean connTmp = reconnect.isEnabled();

    InitializeUI();

    connect.setText(tmp);
    on.setEnabled(onTmp);
    off.setEnabled(offTmp);
    reconnect.setEnabled(connTmp);
}
```

now my `InitializeUI()` method is nothing but a bunch of findViewById's and seetting up the onClickListeners. Also make sure to call `InitializeUI() in your`onCreate()`.

Hope this helps some.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @TronicZomB. I have thought of this approach also. Your example did reminded me to save the states before `InitializeUI()` and restore them later on. But while reading your suggestion, i came up with a solution, which i think is simpler and can solve my problem. Please correct me if it has any shortcomings :)

Comment: What is the new solution that you came up with?