# Android - Execute code when display rotates

Tags: android, rotation, android-configchanges

What I'm trying to do is make it so when the device rotates then a bit of code is executed.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

}
```

I've tried putting what I want to happen inside the above code but, no luck, I've Googled a bit but couldn't find anything either. Is this possible?
Thank in advance for any help! :)

Comment: can u give any example which code do are u tring to execute?

Comment: I found my solution here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15640853/do-something-right-before-screen-rotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use onConfigurationChanged but you need to add a line in the Manifest.

```
<activity android:name=".HelloAndroid"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="orientation">
```

Here is a good [tutorial](http://jnastase.alner.net/archive/2010/10/27/handling-orientation-change-in-android.aspx) about it.