# After screen rotation, findFragmentById() returns a fragment, even if there's no such ID inside the layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have one layout in two orientations - 1 landscape and 1 portrait.

**`/layout-land/main.xml`** has two fragments:

- `<fragment android:id="@+id/fragment1" .. />`
- `<fragment android:id="@+id/fragment2" .. />`

**`/layout/main.xml`** has only one fragment:

- `<fragment android:id="@+id/fragment1" .. />`

Here's the **`MainActivity.java`**:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    firstFragment = (FirstFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1);
    secondFragment = (SecondFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
}
```

Next, I start the `MainActivity.java` in **landscape** mode. In this case,

- Both `firstFragment` and `secondFragment` refers to the fragments in the layout **`layout-land/main.xml`**

Then I rotate the screen to **portrait** mode, and the layout file `layout/main.xml` should be loaded. In this case,

- `firstFragment` refers to the `R.id.fragment1`
- `secondFragment` referes to a non-existant fragment. Accessing any elements inside this throws a NullPointerException. (To be more precise, `secondFragment` is **not** `null` here)

How this `secondFragment` is initialized when there's no fragment defined inside the layout?

---

**Edit: Reason found on Android Developer Documentation at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html:**

> When a configuration change causes the activity hosting these
>   fragments to restart, its new instance may use a different layout that
>   doesn't include the same fragments as the previous layout. In this
>   case all of the previous fragments will still be instantiated and
>   running in the new instance. However, any that are no longer
>   associated with a  tag in the view hierarchy will not have
>   their content view created and will return false from isInLayout().
>   (The code here also shows how you can determine if a fragment placed
>   in a container is no longer running in a layout with that container
>   and avoid creating its view hierarchy in that case.)

Comment: Are you sure second fragment is initialized, check if secondFragment==null

Comment: @viv Yes, surely it's null-checked, and it's not null!

Comment: make sure proper xml is loading, try changing a background a bit, just to check, also see if you have nothing added in config parameter in manifest

Comment: You can check for the orientation dynamically and load the second fragment accordingly. If you are in portrait mode then do not load the second fragment.

Comment: @VishnuHaridas It will obviously throw nullpointer exception as there is not second fragment defined in portrait mode layout file.

Comment: @GrIsHu I ran a debug, it points to an object, a fragment object. But if I access that object's member, it will throw NPE. But the solution that you proposed seems good for this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe it's too late, but I leave it for future programmers with this problem, I had a similar problem and solved it this way.

> **Logic:** Check the screen orientation, and call
>   `findViewById(R.id.fragment2)` only if the screen is on landscape mode.
>   Otherwise start a new intent to the other screen

Non working code;

```
@Override
public void onEventoSeleccionado(Evento e) {

    boolean hayDetalle = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.FrgDetalleEvento) != null);

            if(hayDetalle) {
                SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm",Locale.ENGLISH);
                Log.i("EOLog", "Hay Detalle");
                ((DetalleEventoFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.FrgDetalleEvento)).mostrarDetalle(Long.toString(e.getId()),formatter.format(e.getFecha()));
            }
            else {
                Log.i("EOLog", "No hay detalle");           
                Intent i = new Intent(this,DetalleEventoActivity.class);                                        
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putLong("IDEV", e.getId());           
                b.putLong("FECHA", e.getFecha());           
                i.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(i);
            }

}
```

Working code:

```
@Override
public void onEventoSeleccionado(Evento e) {

      int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

            if(orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm",Locale.ENGLISH);
                Log.i("EOLog", "Hay Detalle");
                ((DetalleEventoFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.FrgDetalleEvento)).mostrarDetalle(Long.toString(e.getId()),formatter.format(e.getFecha()));
            }
            else if(orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                Log.i("EOLog", "No hay detalle");           
                Intent i = new Intent(this,DetalleEventoActivity.class);                                        
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putLong("IDEV", e.getId());           
                b.putLong("FECHA", e.getFecha());           
                i.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(i);
            }else
            {
                Log.i("EOLog", "Dispositivo erroneo");
            }

}
```

I hope that is helpful

Comment: That looks good! Just checking the Orientation and calling the second fragment only when the screen is in LANDSCAPE mode. Surely this will solve the issue. (But still have no idea why the fragment points to a non-existent one!)

Answer (score 3):

You can check like below : 
I assume that you have Fragment1 class for the fragment you get by findFragmentById

```
Fragment1 frg1 =getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.FrgDetalleEvento);
boolean hayDetalle = ( frg1!= null && frg1.isInLayout());
```

It solved the same problem with me, hope it helpful for every of you

Comment: Thanks for adding an answer. Like you said, the method `frg1.isInLayout()` and checking the orientation are the best solutions so far.

Answer (score 0):

please cross check the setContentView() of your activity class.

I think it should be-  setContentView(R.layout.main);

Comment: Oops, sorry for that, I changed it in the question. That was actually intented to be `R.layout.main` in the question!

Comment: I think you have to check screen orientation before finding the fragment 'secondFragment'. Loads the secondFragment only in landscape mode. there are function available to check the screen orientation at run time. During the orientation change the activity will be recreated and try to find both fragments. I don't know this is a right way.. Hope it will help you...

Comment: KD - An answer also proposed that solution. I think that will do good in this case.