# What does FragmentManager retain?

Tags: android

I have an abstract base class for activities which instantiate exactly one fragment:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>


public abstract class SingleFragmentActivity extends Activity {
    protected abstract Fragment createFragment();

    private Fragment m_fragment;
    public Fragment getSingleFragment() { return m_fragment; }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        m_fragment = fm.findFragmentById( R.id.fragmentContainer );
        Log.d("SingleFragment", "fetching a fragment");
        if ( m_fragment == null ) {
            Log.d("SingleFragment", "SingleFragment requires creating a new one");
            m_fragment = createFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction().add( R.id.fragmentContainer, m_fragment ).commit();
        } else {
            Log.d("SingleFragment", "SingleFragment reusing one from fragment manager");
        }
    }
}
```

...plus a simple activity and fragment:

```
public class LoginActivity extends SingleFragmentActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "LOGIN ACTIVITY";

    private LoginFragment m_loginFragment;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG,"onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        m_loginFragment = (LoginFragment) getSingleFragment();
        Log.d(TAG,"...login fragment foo = "+m_loginFragment.getFoo());
        m_loginFragment.setFoo( "Here's a new foo");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() { super.onPause(); Log.d(TAG,"onPause"); }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() { super.onDestroy(); Log.d(TAG,"onDestroy"); }

    @Override
    public void onResume() { super.onResume(); Log.d(TAG,"onResume"); }


    @Override
    protected Fragment createFragment() {
        Log.d(TAG,"createFragment()");
        return new LoginFragment();
    }
}

public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "LOGIN FRAGMENT";

    private String foo = "not set yet";
    public String getFoo() { return foo; }
    public void setFoo(String s) { foo = s; }

    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG,"onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() { super.onPause(); Log.d(TAG,"onPause"); }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() { super.onDestroy(); Log.d(TAG,"onDestroy"); }

    @Override
    public void onResume() { super.onResume(); Log.d(TAG,"onResume"); }
}
```

If I run this code, and rotate the phone after it launches, I see the following log:

```
08-07 15:02:51.310: LOGIN ACTIVITY: onCreate
08-07 15:02:51.340: SingleFragment: fetching a fragment
08-07 15:02:51.340: SingleFragment: SingleFragment requires creating a new one
08-07 15:02:51.340: LOGIN ACTIVITY: createFragment()
08-07 15:02:51.340: LOGIN ACTIVITY: ...login fragment foo = not set yet
08-07 15:02:51.340: LOGIN FRAGMENT: onCreate
08-07 15:02:51.340: LOGIN ACTIVITY: onResume
08-07 15:02:51.340: LOGIN FRAGMENT: onResume
08-07 15:02:59.799: LOGIN FRAGMENT: onPause
08-07 15:02:59.799: LOGIN ACTIVITY: onPause
08-07 15:02:59.809: LOGIN FRAGMENT: onDestroy
08-07 15:02:59.809: LOGIN ACTIVITY: onDestroy
08-07 15:02:59.829: LOGIN ACTIVITY: onCreate
08-07 15:02:59.829: LOGIN FRAGMENT: onCreate
08-07 15:02:59.869: SingleFragment: fetching a fragment
08-07 15:02:59.869: SingleFragment: SingleFragment reusing one from fragment manager
08-07 15:02:59.869: LOGIN ACTIVITY: ...login fragment foo = not set yet
08-07 15:02:59.869: LOGIN ACTIVITY: onResume
08-07 15:02:59.869: LOGIN FRAGMENT: onResume
```

Everything works as expected: rotating the phone causes activity and fragment to be destroyed and recreated; I see the fragment manager restores *something*, but my question is "what?" The member variable foo is not retained, so what is it that is being restored?

Answer (score 0):

Me too had the same problem, and posted a question sometimes ago - [After screen rotation, findFragmentById() returns a fragment, even if there's no such ID inside the layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19534746/after-screen-rotation-findfragmentbyid-returns-a-fragment-even-if-theres-no)

At that time, the documentation at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html was mentioning this:

> When a configuration change causes the activity hosting these
>   fragments to restart, its new instance may use a different layout that
>   doesn't include the same fragments as the previous layout. In this
>   case all of the previous fragments will still be instantiated and
>   running in the new instance. However, any that are no longer
>   associated with a tag in the view hierarchy will not have their
>   content view created and will return false from isInLayout(). (The
>   code here also shows how you can determine if a fragment placed in a
>   container is no longer running in a layout with that container and
>   avoid creating its view hierarchy in that case.)

Now this part doesn't exist on that document.

You can check with `isInLayout()` if this fragment is already added to the layout.