# onCreateView, onActivityCreated and onStart called twice, using fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, rotation

Yes, there are several questions with this title, but I couldn't find the specific answer (or I have missed the point...).

I have a "classic" `fragment` application: a list of items. When I click an item, a description of this item appears.

When I am in `portrait mode`, only list of items are shown. When I click an item, I replace `fragment` of items with `fragment` of description.

When I rotate phone, in landscape, the two `fragments` appears same time in the screen. And when this happens, the above mentioned methods are called twice in the description `fragment`.

So you will say: "the problem is that the description `fragment` was created when you are in `portrait`, and when you rotate phone, android is recovering this already created fragment, and creating another one".

I understand this... but how to avoid recreation of the description fragment, if it is statically defined in the `xml` of the `landscape` layout?

Regards

Comment: You can save your selected fragment in onSaveStateInstance and replace the selected fragment in onRestoreStateInstance, it might prevent the above issue.

Answer (score 1):

For me it sounds that what you are searching for is mentioned here:

https://android.jlelse.eu/handling-orientation-changes-in-android-7072958c442a

maybe also this could be interesting for you:

[Real approach for Avoiding Re-creation of Fragment after Screen Rotate (Official Fragment Developer Guide as example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15536679/real-approach-for-avoiding-re-creation-of-fragment-after-screen-rotate-official)

Answer (score 1):

I have similar issue when I have code to add fragment to activity in the onCreate method. I've solved this issue by checking if savedInstanceState is null. Only in this case add first fragment to activity.